# How to split a string in Flutter while also including delimiters

Tags: flutter, dart

+37.4054-122.0999/
The above coordinates are my output. I want to split the string in such a way that it shows +37.4054 and -122.0999 as substrings which includes the + and - signs.

Comment: Instead of split, just do a regex match of all of the interesting bits, and use the matchgroups to extract the data.  Too many times people are so fixated on split that they forget they can just match what they want to extract.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
string.split(RegExp('(?=[+-])'));
```

Example:

```
  var string = '+37.4054-122.0999';
  var string2 = '-37.4054+122.0999';
  var string3 = '+37.4054+122.0999';
  var string4 = '-37.4054-122.0999';
  var a = string.split(RegExp('(?=[+-])'));
  var b = string2.split(RegExp('(?=[+-])'));
  var c = string3.split(RegExp('(?=[+-])'));
  var d = string4.split(RegExp('(?=[+-])'));

  print(a);
  print(b);
  print(c);
  print(d);
```

Output:

```
[+37.4054, -122.0999]
[-37.4054, +122.0999]
[+37.4054, +122.0999]
[-37.4054, -122.0999]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use `split` method:

```
const string = '+37.4054-122.0999';
final splitted = string.split('-');
print(splitted); //['+37.4054', '122.0999'];
print(splitted[0]); //+37.4054;
print('-' + splitted[1]); //-122.0999;
```

Comment: Sometimes the delimiter might be a plus as well instead of '-' . Will string.split('-','+'); make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
void main() {
 final String coord = '+37.4054-122.0999';
  
  final int plusIndex = coord.indexOf('+');
  final int minusIndex = coord.indexOf('-');
  
  final plus = coord.substring(plusIndex, minusIndex);
  final minus = coord.substring(minusIndex, );
  
  print('plus: $plus, minus: $minus');
}
```

Comment: + and - can come randomly according to the location. Sometimes it might be + in the middle or -